# StackOverflowError while creating JSON from an instance of some class using JsonBuilder

Tags: grails, jsonbuilder

I am creating JSON from an instance of class using `JsonBuilder`.
But I am getting `StackOverflowError`.

I created instance of MyClass, in Grails project.

```
class MyBook {
    def isbn
    def title
    def author
    def publisher
}
```

and the code which would create JSON from an instance of `MyBook` is

```
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def myBook = new MyBook(isbn: '0321774094',
                    title: 'Scala for the Impatient',
                    author: 'Cay S. Horstmann',
                    publisher: 'Addison-Wesley Professional')
jsonBuilder(book: myBook)
println("Using an object")
println(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
```

But I am getting StackOverflowError error.

Stacktrace:

> ```
> Line | Method
> ->>  198 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
> |     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
> |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
> |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
> ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
> Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
> ->>  198 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
> |     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
> |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
> |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
> ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
> Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
> ->>  198 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
> |     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
> |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
> |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
> ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
> Caused by StackOverflowError: null
> ->>  354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
> |    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
> |    412 | loadClass in     ''
> ^    358 | loadClass in     ''
> ```

Stacktrace from grails console:

```
Error |
2015-05-07 11:27:45,974 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResol
ver  - StackOverflowError occurred when processing request: [GET] /grailsDemo/JS
ONBuilderSlurper/index
Stacktrace follows:
Message: Executing action [index] of controller [com.krixi.JSONBuilderSlurperCon
troller]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    Line | Method
->>  198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
->>  198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->>  198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by StackOverflowError: null
->>  354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    412 | loadClass in     ''
^    358 | loadClass in     ''
```

Comment: somewhere in that trace should be code/packages visisble from you.  please provide this part and also correlate the line numbers with your code. more often than not, SO indicates an infinte loop.

Comment: Please check updated Stacktrace from grails console

Comment: After the latest edit you example works well.

Comment: Not working. Thats my original question. I just forgot to mention `def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()` in my question, which was updated.